# echoing in the view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to echo a field of my database in the view, but I'm getting the error:

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/admin_view_report.php
>
> Line Number: 7

When I echo the whole array, it works just fine.  I can't find what's wrong.

Part of my controller:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model('viewreport');
    $data['records']=$this->viewreport->getAllByChk();
    $this->load->view('admin_view_report',$data); 
}
```

Part of my model:

```
function getAllByChk(){
    $q = $this->db->get('info');
    if ($q->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

The view:

```
<?php  foreach($records as $row):?>

    <?php echo $row->subject; ?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

If I only print `data['records']` it gives the following output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [address] => 11/siddeshwari
            [area] => sid
            [lat] => 21
            [lng] => 21
            [subject] => hello
            [problem] => lots of problem
            [image] => 
            [time] => 2011-08-11 23:49:29
            [register_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 1
            [city_city_id] => 1
            [status_status_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [address] => 134 banani
            [area] => banai
            [lat] => 1223
            [lng] => 2133
            [subject] => not working
            [problem] => yesproblem problem problem
            [image] => 
            [time] => 2011-08-12 01:09:44
            [register_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 2
            [city_city_id] => 1
            [status_status_id] => 0
        )

)
```

but when I try to print the problem or subject only it gives the error.

Comment: Can you change <?php echo $row->subject; ?> to <?php print_r($row); ?> and show us the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result_array()` returns you an array of arrays, not of objects.

In your view:

```
$row->subject
```

should be:

```
$row['subject']
```

If you want $row to be an object, change `result_array()` to `result()`.  This will give you an array of objects.

Also `foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)` is redundant.

It's just copying `$q->result_array()` to `$data`.

You don't need to do that, just `return $q->result_array();`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following

```
function getAllByChk()
{
    $q = $this->db->get('info');
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $data->result();
    }
    return false;
 }
```

then in the view

```
if($records) :
    foreach($records as $row) :
      print_r($row);
    endforeach;
else:
    echo 'No Records';
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllByChk(){
    $data = array();
    //remove if
```

Also, fetch result either as object `$q->result()` or `echo $row['subject']`

Answer (score -1):

Also you can return the result()

```
          function getAllByChk(){

$q = $this->db->get('info');
        if ($q->num_rows()>0){
         foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)
          {
           $data[]=$row;

             }
         return $data->result();
          }
             }
```

Comment: That's actually wrong! $data is an array as per the code, it needs to be `$q->result()` and not have the `foreach` which is useless anyway.

Comment: `$data` has no `result()` function, because it's an array.  You want to return `$q->result()`.