# Echo in the view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [echoing in the view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039937/echoing-in-the-view-page)

i'm trying to echo i field from my table. But the following error is showing when i run the code

> Message:  Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/details_view.php
>
> Line Number: 6

the function  of my controller

```
    function index()
{

    //using model
    $data['list'] = $this->Rfetch_model->getdata();
    $this->load->view('Rfetch_view', $data);
}

function get_by_id($id = 0){

    $data['info'] = $this->Rfetch_model->getdata_by_id($id);


    $this->load->view('details_view', $data);
}
```

the function of my model

```
function getdata () {
        $this->db->select ('subject, id, problem'); // field name
        $sql = $this->db->get('info'); // table name
        if ($sql->num_rows () >0) {
            foreach($sql->result() as $row) {
            $data[$row->id] = $row->subject;
            }
            return $data;
         }
    }

    function getdata_by_id($id = 0){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);

        $sql = $this->db->get('info');

        return $sql->result();
    }

}
```

my view (details_view):

```
<?php echo $info->problem;  ?>
```

when i print the info.it gives the following output

```
Array    
(
    [0] => stdClass Object

(

  [id] => 2

            [address] => some
            [area] => some
            [lat] => 1223
            [lng] => 2133
            [subject] => some
            [problem] =>problem
            [image] => 
            [time] => 2011-08-12 01:09:44
            [register_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 2
            [city_city_id] => 1
            [status_status_id] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: what you're doing wrong? well, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039937/echoing-in-the-view-page/7039958

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $info[0]->problem;  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getdata_by_id`, you are returning `$sql->result()`.  This gives an array of objects.  You can use `$sql->row()` to return you an object of just that row.